# How to extract image from excel file and save it to file by C# windows service

Tags: c#, excel, windows-services

In a C# windows service application, I want to extract image from excel file and save it to a file. I wrote this code :

```
foreach Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape shape in CurrentSheet.Shapes)
{
    shape.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);
    if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
    {   
       images.Add(Clipboard.GetImage());
    }
}
```

But the problem is that windows service does not access to clipboard. Does anyone have any solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey, put your error here.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't use WinForms Clipboard to get metadata.

The data stored in a clipboard after .CopyPicture(...) are not *just image data* - they are metadata.

You can access them this way:

public const uint CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14;

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern bool CloseClipboard();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetClipboardData(uint format);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern bool IsClipboardFormatAvailable(uint format);

private Image GetMetaImageFromClipboard()
{
  try
  {
    Bitmap image;
    Metafile emf = null;
    if (OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
      if (IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_ENHMETAFILE))
      {
        var ptr = GetClipboardData(CF_ENHMETAFILE);
        if (!ptr.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
          emf = new Metafile(ptr, true);
      }

      CloseClipboard();
    }

    image = new Bitmap(emf.Width, emf.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);

    g.DrawImage(emf, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
    g.Dispose();
    emf.Dispose();
    return image;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // some logs
    return null;
  }
  finally
  {
    CloseClipboard();
  }

}
```

Then, you can use this like that:

`Bitmap bmp = GetMetaImageFromClipboard(); 
bmp.Save(path);`